# Unity2D: Delete spawn objects once it exits camera's view

Tags: unity, camera

does anyone know how to delete/destoy a spawn object when it exit out of the camera view. I tried using:

```
   void OnBecameVisible() {
      Destroy (gameObject);
     }
```

But it didn't work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I don't know. Oh just a friendly advice my spawned object may enter form any point of the [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpigz.jpg). Thank you :).

Comment: Why would you be checking if the object was *visible*, when it is literally the exact opposite of being *not* visible?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `OnBecameInvisible` instead.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
var obj : Transform;   
if (raycast.transform != obj)
    Destroy(obj.gameObject);
```

where `obj` is your object. This needs to be applied to your camera. This should work.

Comment: Thank you, but could you convert it to c# . Please and Thank you

Comment: I usally use javascript, but here you go: public Transform //name of object//; if (RaycastHit.transform != //name of object//) { Destroy(//name of object//) }

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out once I fix unity, I'm having a bug

Comment: Alright, and make sure to vote for my answer!

Comment: @TheMattBat999, this answer confused me. Especially considering a far easier to understand solution was posted not 20 seconds after yours. You have raised, previously, that you are "just trying to help". Since you mean well, I thought I would address that this site favors *quality* over *quantity*. You might mean well, but if you keep posting answers that get down-voted, the system actually *blocks* you from posting any more answers. Test out your material, assume the audience is not "a genius" like you, and consider formatting to make your answers more presentable.

Comment: Hopefully I have not come across as rude or offensive, as I do not mean to be. But when you seem eager to help, and ask for feedback where negative feedback can block you from posting to the site, it is worth addressing sooner rather than later.